# jQuery interface for creating ics valid repeating rules (rrule)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, icalendar, rrule

Looking for an interface for creating ics valid RRULE strings, similar to Google Calendar's. Most of the calendars I've looked at handle ics RRULEs pretty similar and their interfaces are nearly identical. Would like to use an open source solution if one exists.

The interface would populate a hidden text field with a valid RRULE string: `FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU`

Google Calendar's:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, but since there aren't many I'm going to write them down (maybe going to save some time to anyone looking for such interface).

After some research I've found two:

Fuel UX:

https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux (deprecated, edited in 2021)

jquery.recurrenceinput.js:
https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js/blob/master/README.rst

Hope this helps anyone.